# Can't access my Post values send through with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

**EDIT**: Removing the 'index.php' with .htaccess creates this probem I just discovered. Now I'm on to resolving it.

**EDIT**: Problem solved. The javascript was wrong: `url: "/login/"` It needed a trailing slash.

**ORIGINAL**: In my home view, I created a form:

```
<div id="login"><?php 
echo form_open('login');
echo form_input('username', 'Username', 'id="username"');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Login', 'id="login_submit"');
echo form_close();
?></div>
```

With some basic javascript (thanks to Nettuts) I tried to implement some ajax:

```
$('#login_submit').click(function() {

var form_data = {
    username: $('#username').val(),
    password: $('#password').val()      
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/login",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#login').html(msg);
    }
});

return false;
});
```

As you can see, it sends the form values to the login controller.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        echo '<h2>Login succeeded with ajax</h2>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>But your ajax failed miserably</p>';
    }
}

}
```

**The problem is, it doesn't work.** The function `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` outputs FALSE. Ignoring that, every other post data is missing. **Nothing is put through.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is your jQuery click handler `$(document).ready(...` wrapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem could be that you're not actually sending to the correct script. Your url /login doesn't look like it will get to a Codeigniter URL (http://domain.com/index.php/login or http://domain.com/my_app/index.php/login).

Try changing the url to either the full url location of the controller or to a proper absolute path. Either:

```
url: "http://yourdomain.com/index.php/login",
```

or

```
url: "/my_app/index.php/login",
```

Unless you've rewritten the urls then /login probably won't contact the correct script.

Comment: I edited the code a bit. The script does work and the controller with its index() method does get called. Echoing something out actually replaces the div with its content. It's the post data that doesn't come through. :(

Comment: Can you console.log() form_data before you send it and make sure that the data is what you're expecting? Also make sure you're wrapping the jQuery in $(document).ready(function () { //jQuery } otherwise jQuery won't be able to correctly get the value of the input fields.

Comment: I added document ready function. Firebug says: Object { username="Username", password="Password"} It seems that the post data is correctly set.

Comment: Removing the 'index.php' with .htaccess creates this probem I just discovered. Now I'm on to resolving it.

Comment: Looks like you were right in the first place. The url was kinda wrong. It needed a trailing slash. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This set me in the right direction when i was using  PHP and Jquery AJAX to send post values. I am using .htaccess to rewrite the url so as to remove the .php extension. Post values were not being passed on to my sendmail.php file. I solved this by changing the url of the post request from

```
$.ajax({
                            url:'sendemail.php',
                            method:'post',
                            data:{
                                fname:fname,
                            },
                            success:function (e) {
                                alert(e);
                            }
                        });
```

to

```
url:'/sendmail'
```